# Implement GLSurfaceView layer under MultiTouch View in Android

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-sensors, glsurfaceview

I have my custom multi-touch view which is referenced by my Main Activity. Now, I want to implement motion sensors on this screen (Rotation_Vector) which uses GLSurfaceView.

Rotation_Vector is able to return values if it runs under a separate activity but I want to make it work on the same screen which uses my Multi-Touch view. How can I combine GLSurface View and MultiTouch view in the same activity and what changes do I need to make in my xml?

Currently, this is how my xml looks like:

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/background1">

    <android.opengl.GLSurfaceView android:id="@+id/surfaceviewclass"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <com.example.gcdt.MultiTouchView
        android:id="@+id/multi_touch_view" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

But when I try to reference it in my activity something like this, it gives me null pointer exception:

```
    mGLSurfaceView = (GLSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceviewclass);
```